# Stripe - Radar Rules

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

Hope you are doing well.
I am going through the following documentation of Stripe "https://stripe.com/docs/radar/radar-session". In the following page it is mentioned We have to create Radar session at client side and send it your server and after that we have to send from server to stripe. So my question is where we have to define rules (Block if :card_country: = 'CA' OR :card_country: = 'DE' OR :card_country: = 'AE') at client side or server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the rules in your Stripe account's dashboard, not through code neither on the front or backend. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/radar/rules